# How to reference Lambda response data to Output in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to reference the Lambda `response_data` or `return` or any other variable value into the CloudFormation Output? so I can export the output for using as Cross Stack Referencing.

```
Resources:
  EC2CustomResource:
    Type: Custom::EC2CustomResource
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt AWSLambdaFunction.Arn
        
  AWSLambdaFunction:
     Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
     Properties:
       Description: "bucket!"
       FunctionName: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-${AWS::Region}-lambda'
       Handler: index.handler
       Timeout: 360
       Runtime: python3.9
       Code:
         ZipFile: |
           import boto3
           import cfnresponse   
           
           def handler(event, context):
           
               response_data = {}
               s3 = boto3.client('s3')
               
               # dummy test
               testList = [1, 2, 3]
               
               try:
                   print("Execution succesfull!")
                   response_data['testList'] = testList
                   cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, response_data)
               except Exception as e:
                   print("Execution failed...")
                   response_data['Data'] = str(e)
                   cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.FAILED, response_data)

# This is not working
Outputs:
  LambdaFunctionOutput: 
    Value: !GetAtt AWSLambdaFunction.response_data['testList']
    Description: Return Value of Lambda Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template you've specified only creates a Lambda function. It will not execute this lambda function. If you want to execute a lambda function and reference some return value, you'll have to use a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) backed by a lambda function.

Edit #1

The response data you've defined and passed along using the `cfnresponse` library, can be retrieved using the cfn `!GetAtt` function as stated in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/crpg-ref-responses.html).

> Data:
> Optional. The custom resource provider-defined name-value pairs to send with the response. You can access the values provided here by name in the template with Fn::GetAtt.

Comment: yes, forgot to copy&paste it, but still how you reference it to output?

Comment: I've edited my response to include the answer.

Comment: I will get `Requested attribute response_data['testList'] does not exist in schema for AWS::Lambda::Function. Rollback requested by user.`

Comment: You only have to put 'testList' amd have to reference the CR. So '!GetAtt EC2CustomResource.testList'